# Setting the maximum width of a Bokeh plot

Tags: bokeh

I understand that I can make a Bokeh plot responsive to the width of a div by setting `responsive=True`. However, I am interested in having the Bokeh plot only be responsive up to a point. Is there a method so that I can set the maximum width of the Bokeh plot so that the figure is not responsive up to a certain div width? I have looked in the documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0` there is no such explicit option. However, bokeh plots (and other layout items) now have a `sizing_mode` property with a wider range of options: `"fixed"`, `"stretch_both"`, `"scale_width"`, `"scale_height"`, and `"scale_both"`. So if you can put a Bokeh plot with one of the non-fixed sizing modes in div that responds the way you describe (e.g. perhaps a Bootstrap container) then the plot will respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the options to limit the maximum size a responsive bokeh plot can reach that worked for me are:

1. To have the bokeh layout stretch across the whole width of the div I used `sizing_mode="scale_both"` and then used `max_width=` to limit the maximum size the plot can reach within the layout. I also tried `max_height=` but that did not work.
2. Alternatively, limit the width of the div  of the bokeh layout div with
   `<div style="max-width:   ">`. Here, again, `<div style="max-height:   ">` did not work.